# BMW link app not working on iPhone 5 after restoring my phone

Tags: iphone, applications, bluetooth

I have a iPhone 5 and I downloaded the BMW link app which was paired up with my BMW S ONE. For some reason after I reset my phone it no longer pairs up with my car as if I have failed to switch something on with my phone. However, Bluetooth works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the BMW link app connect? Using WiFi? Enable WiFi?

Comment: Bluetooth and that is connected

Comment: Does the BMW app has something special which you must connect? Try rebooting your iDevice by holding down power button and home button till the Apple displays.

Comment: I reset my phone as apple asked me to do so after there was problem with notes on there. Once I did this my bmw link failed to sync up with the car. I am sure that something has switched off on my phone by resetting it but I just don't know what?

Comment: did the reboot thing and tried again but, no joy!

Comment: The Link app does connect to my BMW via Bluetooth but it sort of freezes the player, i.e. I cannot do anything but make and receive calls through the integrated system. For some reason it doesn’t allow me to play songs even though the screen show it’s connected. I’ve downloaded the BMW Connected app and will try to see if it works.